# What is the difference between a leased line and EFM?

Tags: internet, networking

I am ordering a new internet connection in the United Kingdom and wondered what's the difference between:

- 10mb leased line
- 10mb EFM (Ethernet First Mile) line

They both seem to offer equal contention and the same speed but the lease line is £30 more a month.

Comment: When you say equal contention, I assume you mean none? Leased lines generally don't have any contention. I don't have any EFM circuits so I can't comment on those, I'd be interested to know if yours is offered with contention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they from the same company?
Do they have the same terms and conditions?

It might be that the leased line has a stricter contract, with for example uptime guarantees or other clauses that the supplier has to meet.

Are they both symmetric lines do they both include unlimited bandwidth?

They are lots of questions which would need answering, which we can't help you with as we don't have the companies details and their individual terms and conditions.

Comment: thanks, I will look at all these points and come back with some answers!